# Implement actix_web::Responder trait on a custom structure

Tags: rust, traits, actix-web

I'm using actix-web v4.

I'm trying to implement a web service with a custom structure for handling errors:

```rust
pub struct ApiError {
    pub message: String,
    pub code: ErrorEnum,
    pub details: Vec<ErrorDetail>,
}
```

This is an example of function that returns this structure on a failure:

```rust
pub fn my_func_that_fails() -> Result<(), ApiError> {
    Err(ApiError::default())
}
```

I have this function to map `ApiError`s to `HttpResponse`s:

```rust
pub fn err_to_http(error: &ApiError) -> actix_web::HttpResponse {
    match error.code {
        ErrorEnum::NotFound => actix_web::HttpResponse::NotFound()
            .content_type("application/json; charset=utf-8")
            .json(error),
        //...
    }
}
```

This is how I use it in a handler:

```rust
pub async fn my_handler(req: actix_web::HttpRequest) -> impl actix_web::Responder {
    if let Err(e) = my_func_that_fails() {
        return err_to_http(&e);
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to use it this way:

```rust
pub async fn my_handler(req: actix_web::HttpRequest) -> impl actix_web::Responder {
    my_func_that_fails()?;
}
```

For this I need to implement the trait `actix_web::Responder`, but I can't find documentation online to do that. This is my attempt at doing it, but I don't know what to put in the `Body` type, nor if I'm doing it correctly:

```rust
impl actix_web::Responder for ApiError {
    type Body = ???;

    fn respond_to(self, req: &actix_web::HttpRequest) -> actix_web::HttpResponse<Self::Body> {
        err_to_http(&self.api_error).into_future()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```rs
impl actix_web::Responder for ApiError {
    type Body = actix_web::body::BoxBody;

    fn respond_to(self, req: &actix_web::HttpRequest) -> actix_web::HttpResponse<Self::Body> {
        err_to_http(&self.api_error)
    }
}
```

Although, this technically isn't accurate because implementing `Responder` for ApiError will not solve your problem. I recommend something like this instead:

```rs
pub async fn my_handler(req: actix_web::HttpRequest) -> Result<actix_web::HttpResponse, ApiError> {
    my_func_that_fails()?;
}
```

and then have `ApiError` implement the `ResponseError` trait, like so:

```rs
impl actix_web::error::ResponseError for ApiError {
    fn error_response(&self) -> actix_web::HttpResponse {
        match error.code {
            ErrorEnum::NotFound => actix_web::HttpResponse::NotFound()
                .content_type("application/json; charset=utf-8")
                .json(error),
            //...
        }
    }

    fn status_code(&self) -> actix_web::http::StatusCode {
        // get status code here
    }
}
```

Comment: It works as you said, thank you !